# how can I make Join on different data types of column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables student and student card . in student I have student Id which is number having values 112, 113, 114 but in student card, I have student id with character S like S112, S113.

Is there anyway I can put join on both table by trimming S in the statement .

Not sure if its possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the correct logic in your join condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM student s
INNER JOIN student_card sc
    ON SUBSTRING(sc.student_id, 2) = s.id;
```

This compares the student ID in the student card table from the second character onwards against the full student ID in the student table.  Note that strictly speaking we should do a cast from text to integer, or maybe vice-versa, but MySQL is able to handle implicit conversions, so the above logic alone should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`SELECT * FROM studdent s INNER JOIN student_card sc on 'S'||s.id=sc.student_id`

Comment: This is actually a better solution.  There is some hope that it can use an index on `student_card(student_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the S character using `replace()` and then `convert it to int` like below -

```
select * from student s inner join studentcard sc
on s.studentid=cast(replace(sc.studentid,'S','') as UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: or  `on concat('S',s.student_id)=sc.studentid`, depending if you want the query to use an index in sc or s